# Deserializing JSON into string array

Tags: c#, .net, json

I just started dabbling with C#, and I've been banging my head over JSON deserialization for a while now. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json library. I'm expecting just a json response of an array of dictionaries as such

```
[{"id":"669","content":" testing","comments":"","ups":"0","downs":"0"}, {"id":"482","content":" test2","comments":"","ups":"0","downs":"0"}]
```

Right now I have:    (note: download is just a string holding the json string)

```
string[] arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(download);
```

I've tried many different ways of doing this, each failed. Is there a standard way for parsing json of this type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have an array of **objects** not strings. Create a class that maps the properties and deserialize into that,

```
public class MyClass {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string ups { get; set; }
    public string downs { get; set; }
}

MyClass[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass[]>(download);
```

There are only a few basic types in JSON, but it is helpful to learn and recognize them. Objects, Arrays, strings, etc. http://www.json.org/ and http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp are good resources to get started. For example a string array in JSON would look like,

```
["One", "Two", "Three"]
```

Comment: You're welcome! In addition to serializing into a strongly typed class, you can use `JObject.Parse(jsonstring)`. This returns a JObject which you can then access the properties of like `obj.Value<string>("content")`. Of course the strongly typed approach is recommend, but it's good to know the alternatives :)

Comment: @Despertar What does (download) exacly stand for?

Comment: @Fernando This was the variable Chris was using, it holds the json string that needs to be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

I implement this and hope this is helpful all.

```
 var jsonResponse = 
  [{"Id":2,"Name":"Watch"},{"Id":3,"Name":"TV"},{"Id":4,"Name":""}]

 var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(jsonResponse);
```

where MyClass is the entity

```
 public class MyClass
            {
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
            }
```