# Returning an array as a string with Web Api 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api 2 end point that returns Json containing an array of image urls. The response from it looks like this

```
   {
    "Status": 0,
    "Message": "Success",
    "Images": [
        "http://some.image.com/somepath/SomeReport-0.png",
        "http://some.image.com/somepath/SomeReport-1.png"
    ]
   }
```

I would like the json array to return as an array string. How would I need to set up my response in order to accomplish that? I currently set up the array and the response using this method

```
// response.status and response.message are added before this

response.Images = imagePaths.Select(x => string.Format(urlString, Path.GetFileName(x)));

HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
```

purpose for needing the array returned in string format is so I can appended it to an html data-attribute. Right now if I reference the response like so:

```
listItem.append('<a class="dd-option" data-path="' + response.Images + '" href="#"></a>');
```

The content inside the attribute looks like

```
data-attr="http://some.url.com/somepath/ReportStore/image-0.png,http://some.url.com/somepath/ReportStore/image-1.png"
```

rather than

```
data-attr="["http://some.url.com/somepath/ReportStore/image-0.png","http://some.url.com/somepath/ReportStore/image-1.png"]"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON into string array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640028/deserializing-json-into-string-array)

Comment: How about just using the javascript join() function? `response.Images.join(", ")`.

Comment: hmm that's an interesting idea, I will give that a shot.

Comment: @Jasen Unfortunately that did not work, I need the array returned as a string itself.

Comment: It is possible in c# as well https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this in javascript then you can JSON.stringify

```js
var jsonResponse = 
    {
    "Status": 0,
    "Message": "Success",
    "Images": [
        "http://some.image.com/somepath/SomeReport-0.png",
        "http://some.image.com/somepath/SomeReport-1.png"
    ]
   }

 var images = JSON.stringify(jsonResponse.Images);

console.log(images);

$("#foo").append($("<li>").text("foo").attr("data-foo", images));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="foo">
</ul>
```

This will give you

```
<li data-foo="["http://some.image.com/somepath/SomeReport-0.png","http://some.image.com/somepath/SomeReport-1.png"]">foo</li>
```

But you need to mind the quotes as it may generate invalid html.

However, even if you had

```
data-attr="http://some.url.com/somepath/ReportStore/image-0.png,http://some.url.com/somepath/ReportStore/image-1.png"
```

which you could get server-side with a `String.join()` then you can use javascript split() on this to get the array back again.

```
var imagesArr = ($(this).data("attr")).split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just map the images to an array of strings and return that object from your controller.

```
public string[] Get()
{
     //create this array object from your images object
     return new string[]{"imagePath1", "imagePath2", "imagePath3"};
}
```